# Polars calculate percentile

Tags: python, python-polars

I have a polars dataframe that hava a column with dates and others with prices and I want to calculate the percentile of each one in a window of 252 x 3 observations.

For that I'm doing this:

```py
prices = prices.sort(by=["date"])
rank_cols = list(set(prices.columns).difference("date"))

percentiles = (
    prices.sort(by=["date"])
    .set_sorted("date")
    .group_by_dynamic(
        index_column=["date"], every="1i", start_by="window", period="756i"
    )
    .agg(
        [
            (pl.col(col).rank() * 100.0 / pl.col(col).count()).alias(
                f"{col}_percentile"
            )
            for col in rank_cols
        ]
    )
)
```

But the exception is throwing is:

```py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 6, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/polars/dataframe/group_by.py", line 1047, in agg
    self.df.lazy()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/polars/lazyframe/frame.py", line 1706, in collect
    return wrap_df(ldf.collect())
polars.exceptions.InvalidOperationError: argument in operation 'group_by_dynamic' is not explicitly sorted

- If your data is ALREADY sorted, set the sorted flag with: '.set_sorted()'.
- If your data is NOT sorted, sort the 'expr/series/column' first.
```

In the code I already do as the suggestion indicates, but the exception persists.

EDIT:

Make some changes according to @Hericks suggestion.

```
import polars as pl
import pandas as pd
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

# Generate 10 dates starting from today
start_date = datetime.now().date()
date_list = [start_date + timedelta(days=i) for i in range(10)]

# Generate random prices for each date and column
data = {
    'date': date_list,
    'asset_1': [float(f"{i+1}.{i+2}") for i in range(10)],
    'asset_2': [float(f"{i+2}.{i+3}") for i in range(10)],
    'asset_3': [float(f"{i+3}.{i+4}") for i in range(10)],
}


prices = pl.DataFrame(data)

prices = prices.cast({"date": pl.Date})


rank_cols = list(set(prices.columns).difference("date"))

percentiles = (
    prices.sort(by=["date"])
    .set_sorted("date")
    .group_by_dynamic(
        index_column="date", every="1i", start_by="window", period="4i"
    )
    .agg(
        [
            (pl.col(col).rank() * 100.0 / pl.col(col).count()).alias(
                f"{col}_percentile"
            )
            for col in rank_cols
        ]
    )
)
```

Now I'm getting

```
pyo3_runtime.PanicException: attempt to divide by zero
```

EDIT 2:

The problem is the date use, I changed the dates by integers and something worked up. (Also added first to take the first register)

```py
import polars as pl


int_list = [i+1 for i in range(6)]

# Generate random prices for each date and column
data = {
    'int_index': int_list,
    'asset_1': [1.1, 3.4, 2.6, 4.8, 7.4, 3.2],
    'asset_2': [4, 7, 8, 3, 4, 5],
    'asset_3': [1, 3, 10, 20, 2, 4],
}


# Convert the Pandas DataFrame to a Polars DataFrame
prices = pl.DataFrame(data)


rank_cols = list(set(prices.columns).difference("int_index"))

percentiles = (
    prices.sort(by="int_index")
    .set_sorted("int_index")
    .group_by_dynamic(
        index_column="int_index", every="1i", start_by="window", period="4i"
    )
    .agg(
        [
            (pl.col(col).rank().first() * 100.0 / pl.col(col).count()).alias(
                f"{col}_percentile"
            )
            for col in rank_cols
        ]
    )
)
```

EDIT 3:

The idea is given the index i take the values on index i, i+1, i+2, i+3 and calculate the percentile rank of the register i with respect the four ones.

For example for in asset_1 for the first index (1) the sample (with the three next registers) is:

1.1, 3.4, 2.6, 4.8 so the percentile of the first register is 25

For the asset_1 the second index (2) the sample (with the three next registers) is:

3.4, 2.6, 4.8 and 7.4 so the percentile is 50.

Comment: Did you try `.set_sorted("date")`?

Comment: @Hericks yes, I also edited the question, and the exception is the same. Thanks

Comment: What type is your _date_ column? It sounds like `pl.Date`, but you specify integer steps in `pl.DataFrame.group_by_dynamic`. In general, a reproducible example with expected input/output would be helpful.

Comment: @Hericks Yes is pl.Date but I don't want to specify a number of days (because I'm using business days)

- So I must generate a list of integers and use them instead of the dates?

- Also I noted that is calculating the data with forward data, how can I calculate it backwards?

Comment: Try to remove the brackets around `"date"` in `pl.DataFrame.sort()` and the _index_column_ of the `pl.DataFrame.group_by_dynamic()`. This works for me, but another issue regarding `pl.Date` index and integer steps is raised. To solve the entire problem, a reproducible example is needed.

Comment: @Hericks I made the changes you suggested and also I aggregated the a reproducible example. Thanks

Comment: @rlartiga could you also add a desired outcome for your input example?

Comment: The division by 0 comes from mixing `pl.Date` with integer steps.

Comment: @Hericks thanks now it works. I changed the date to an int list and also used rank().first() to take the first register.

Comment: @rlartiga honestly it's still unclear for me what is it you trying to achieve. For the results which I get from you example your code seems a bit more complicated than necessary

Comment: @RomanPekar I tried to add an explanation of what I want to do in the last edit.
Basically I want to calculate a rolling percentile rank taking a window of n registers.

Comment: but in your example code you don't really use the values, you only use `rank()`. Plus, your values are ever increasing, so your percentiles will be 25 for any full window.
again, the best way to ask a question is to add good representative input / desired output. And make it as small as possible to be more clear

Comment: @RomanPekar I fixed the example to show non monotonic data. Also I suppose that the rank is taking in consideration the window given by the dynamic group by. Thanks by the suggestion

Comment: @RomanPekar what do you think I should create I new question with a more clear explanation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm still a bit guessing on what you would expect as an answer, but you can probably work you way from this one

So, given your example data:

```py
import polars as pl

# Generate random prices for each date and column
prices = pl.DataFrame({
    'int_index': range(6),
    'asset_1': [1.1, 3.4, 2.6, 4.8, 7.4, 3.2],
    'asset_2': [4, 7, 8, 3, 4, 5],
    'asset_3': [1, 3, 10, 20, 2, 4],
})

┌───────────┬─────────┬─────────┬─────────┐
│ int_index ┆ asset_1 ┆ asset_2 ┆ asset_3 │
│ ---       ┆ ---     ┆ ---     ┆ ---     │
│ i64       ┆ f64     ┆ i64     ┆ i64     │
╞═══════════╪═════════╪═════════╪═════════╡
│ 0         ┆ 1.1     ┆ 4       ┆ 1       │
│ 1         ┆ 3.4     ┆ 7       ┆ 3       │
│ 2         ┆ 2.6     ┆ 8       ┆ 10      │
│ 3         ┆ 4.8     ┆ 3       ┆ 20      │
│ 4         ┆ 7.4     ┆ 4       ┆ 2       │
│ 5         ┆ 3.2     ┆ 5       ┆ 4       │
└───────────┴─────────┴─────────┴─────────┘
```

Using [`rolling()`](https://docs.pola.rs/py-polars/html/reference/dataframe/api/polars.DataFrame.rolling.html#polars.DataFrame.rolling) to create windows and then (the same as you did in your question) - `rank().first()` divided by `count()`, `name.suffix()` to assign new names to the columns:

```py
cols = pl.all().exclude('int_index')

percentiles = (
    prices.sort(by="int_index")
    .rolling(index_column="int_index", period="4i", offset="0i", closed="left")
    .agg((cols.rank().first() * 100 / cols.count()).name.suffix('_percentile'))
)

┌───────────┬────────────────────┬────────────────────┬────────────────────┐
│ int_index ┆ asset_1_percentile ┆ asset_2_percentile ┆ asset_3_percentile │
│ ---       ┆ ---                ┆ ---                ┆ ---                │
│ i64       ┆ f64                ┆ f64                ┆ f64                │
╞═══════════╪════════════════════╪════════════════════╪════════════════════╡
│ 0         ┆ 25.0               ┆ 50.0               ┆ 25.0               │
│ 1         ┆ 50.0               ┆ 75.0               ┆ 50.0               │
│ 2         ┆ 25.0               ┆ 100.0              ┆ 75.0               │
│ 3         ┆ 66.666667          ┆ 33.333333          ┆ 100.0              │
│ 4         ┆ 100.0              ┆ 50.0               ┆ 50.0               │
│ 5         ┆ 100.0              ┆ 100.0              ┆ 100.0              │
└───────────┴────────────────────┴────────────────────┴────────────────────┘
```

you can also check what's inside of each window:

```py
(
    prices.sort(by="int_index")
    .rolling(index_column="int_index", period="4i", offset="0i", closed="left")
    .agg(cols)
)
┌───────────┬───────────────────┬─────────────┬───────────────┐
│ int_index ┆ asset_1           ┆ asset_2     ┆ asset_3       │
│ ---       ┆ ---               ┆ ---         ┆ ---           │
│ i64       ┆ list[f64]         ┆ list[i64]   ┆ list[i64]     │
╞═══════════╪═══════════════════╪═════════════╪═══════════════╡
│ 0         ┆ [1.1, 3.4, … 4.8] ┆ [4, 7, … 3] ┆ [1, 3, … 20]  │
│ 1         ┆ [3.4, 2.6, … 7.4] ┆ [7, 8, … 4] ┆ [3, 10, … 2]  │
│ 2         ┆ [2.6, 4.8, … 3.2] ┆ [8, 3, … 5] ┆ [10, 20, … 4] │
│ 3         ┆ [4.8, 7.4, 3.2]   ┆ [3, 4, 5]   ┆ [20, 2, 4]    │
│ 4         ┆ [7.4, 3.2]        ┆ [4, 5]      ┆ [2, 4]        │
│ 5         ┆ [3.2]             ┆ [5]         ┆ [4]           │
└───────────┴───────────────────┴─────────────┴───────────────┘
```

Comment: That's perfect!
Also I noted that it don't have a min_periods as in pandas to define the minimum size of the window to do the calculation.